# cannot read property to String of undefined [sequelize db:migrate node.js postgres]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I run

```
$ sequelize db:migrate,
```

but I get this result, with an ERROR

```
Loaded Configuration file "db\config\config.json".
Using environment "development".
==20190927081141-add-email-to-contacts: migrating =======

ERROR: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

This is my current config.json file, but I don't have any toString property in it.

```
//config.json

{
  "development": {
    "port":5432,
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": null,
    "database": "address-bloc-dev",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "logging":false
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": null,
    "database": "address-bloc-test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "logging": false
  }
}
```

Here is also the add email to contacts.js file

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn('Contacts', 'email',
     {
      email: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn('Contacts', 'email');
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm struggling in figuring it out.

Thank you

Federico

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue with
**changeColumn()**, ensure that that you completely define the new data type of the column that you intend to change.

[Sequelize Docs](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/migrations/#changecolumntablename-attributename-datatypeoroptions-options)
*This method changes the meta data of an attribute. It is possible to change the default value, allowance of null or the data type. Please make sure, that you are completely describing the new data type.*

Comment: @Smartninggs, When I am setting allowNull:false it is throwing the same error! I have only this allowNull propery needs to set! So Do I need to put other things as well like default value, datatype?

Answer (score 1):

This error is not coming from the `config.json` file, but rather the `20190927081141-add-email-to-contacts`. The error is from there.

EDIT:

What you are doing wrong is how you are setting the type of the email field.

You should do:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn('Contacts', 'email',
     {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
     });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn('Contacts', 'email');
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you, I have just included it into the question

Answer (score 1):

I have this error and the solution was to modify just a word.

the place of the error

```
  id:{
      ype: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    }
```

the solution was

```
 id:{
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV1,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    }
```

just added the missing letter

Answer (score 0):

follow steps below:

1. install  sequelize-cli:  `npm install -g sequelize-cli`
2. install sequelize: `npm install --save sequelize`
3. install mysql2: npm install --save mysql2
4. initialize sequelize:  sequelize init
5. delete the migration and seeder directory automatically generated
6. create a model (e.g user model):

   ```
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
       const User = sequelize.define('users', {
         name: {
                type: Datatype.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
               },

         userRole: {
                type: Datatype.INTEGER,
                allowNull: false,
               },
     });
   return User;
   ```

   }
7. Add `db.sequelize.sync({ force: true, logging: console.log });` to your server.js after db has been defined.
8. run your server